# Excel/MacOS - CHAR(13) doesn't render in cell

Tags: excel, macos

As you can see in the screenshot the break is visible in the formula bar but not in the cell.

This value has been copied from a column where the CHAR(13) is added via the SUBSTITUTE function.

Also if I add another line break after 3 with Shift+Ctrl+Enter and then remove it the cell updates and then the first break is rendered properly.

Does anyone know why this keeps happening?

Thanks in advance.

[image: In formula bar the break is visible but not in the cell below]

Comment: Make sure you have `Wrap Text` on for that cell.

Comment: I think it's a char 10 instead. Also if you tick text wrapping it should show correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try a carriage return and then a line feed: `=CONCAT("A",CHAR(13),CHAR(10),"B")`